# getting location in android on a map

Tags: android, google-maps, location

if i have the latitude and longitude and i want to open up Google maps to that specific location how do i do so? which intent launches Google maps with a given latitude and longitude to display?
 i have this intent but this intent looks for navigation... i only want it to display the location at the given latitude and longitude

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat
                            + "," + lon));
 intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
                    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this :

```
String uriName = "geo:"+ lat+ "," + lon;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

*It will show map For Latitude and longitude*

For Specific location:

```
String uriName = "geo:"+ lat+ "," + lon+ "?q=my+street+address";
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriName)));
```

[Other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256801/how-to-launch-map-intent-with-a-marker-overlay-item-at-given-latitude-and-longit)